# Conversion to CNF (stuck)

Tags: logic, cnf, conjunctive-normal-form

I've managed to simplify an expression to the following (both the original expression and the version below resolve to the same CNF according to WolphramAlpha).

What next?

```
(~C || C || ~A) && (~A || ~B || C)
```

Comment: WolphramAlpha says:


~A || ~B || C

.. how?

Comment: This is really easy. Take a look at the rules involving `true` and `false` again. Start with the subterm `~C || C`.

Comment: @GhostGambler Do you mean this equates to:
(True || ~A) && (~A || ~B || C) //
True && (~A || ~B || C) //
(~A || ~B || C)

Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct